# How to modify ScrollPane using synth L&F?

Tags: java, xml, swing, jscrollpane, synth

I want to modify `ScrollPane` using Synth L&F

Here is my XML code:

```xml
<style id="scrollBar">
    <insets top="4" left="6" bottom="4" right="6"/>

    <state>
        <font name="Verdana" size="12"/>
        <color value="#D2DFF2" type="BACKGROUND"/>
        <color value="#000000" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <imagePainter method="scrollBarBackground" path="scrollbar.png" sourceInsets="4 6 4 6" paintCenter="true"/>
</style>

<bind style="scrollBar" type="region" key="ScrollBar"/>
```

Is there any link where I can find all the methods and regions and subregions details?

Comment: That is very strange.  I expected the Google code script used to format (color) the XML to apply the same type of style to the `insets` element (etc.) as it did for the `style` and `bind` elements.  The fact that it does not is *usually* because of an invalid character or missed quote somewhere in the content, but I sure can't see anything wrong with the XML fragment presented..